# How to change class/property name?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, nameof

For example:

```
public class Car{

     public string color {get; set;}

     public int VINCode {get;set;}

}
```

Now if I call `nameof(Car)` it returns "Car"

```
[Name("something")]
public class Car{

     [Name("something_else")]
     public string color {get; set;}

     public int VINCode {get;set;}

}
```

But how can I get nameof to return the value in the Name attribute rather than  the name of the class or method. eg: `nameof(Car) == "something"` or `nameof(Car.color) == "something_else"`.

the problem:

```
var modelState = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(data);

        var departmentViewModels = modelState[nameof(DepartmentListView.DepartmentsViewModels)][0];
        var departmentTypes = modelState[nameof(DepartmentListView.DepartmentsViewModels)][0];
```

fixing for that:

```
var modelState = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DepartmentListView>(data);

        var departmentViewModels = modelState.DepartmentsViewModels;
        var departmentTypes = modelState.DepartmentTypes;
```

Serialization of this:

```
public class DepartmentListView
    {
        public IEnumerable<DepartmentViewModel> DepartmentsViewModels { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<DepartmentType> DepartmentTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

will be:

```
departmentsViewModel : [], departmentTypes : [] (with lowercase)
```

I know I can change that lowercase serialization with **JsonProperty**, but I thought that I will can change the name of class or property...

Comment: You want to take a feature that was created so that you can have strong compile-time guarantees of name matches, rather than relying on the brittle use of strings and... re-introduce a brittle use of strings?

Comment: `nameof` was designed specifically for using the current name of the class, variable, etc.  The intent was that if a name was changed, programmers wouldn't have to change hard-coded, literal text everywhere.

Comment: Agreed, question feels a bit odd, perhaps if you explain what you're ultimately trying to accomplish, maybe there is just a more practical way to achieve it.

Comment: This seems like a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) scenario

Comment: You're not making things much clearer with your edits. I can't understand what "the problem" is by just being shown a chunk of code. Similarly, what "fixing for that" even means when it's just another chunk of code isn't clear. I'd suggest you read some of the resources already linked here and also about [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do it with `nameof`.

But if you want to get the value of a `CustomAttribute` you can try this:

```
// I assume this is your Name class
public class Name: Attribute
{
    public string Data { get; }
    public Name(string data) { Data = data; }
}
```

Then you can

```
// Will return "something"
var classAttrData = ((Name) typeof(Car).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Name))).Data;

// Will return "something_else"
var fieldAttrData = ((Name) typeof(Car).GetField(nameof(Car.color)).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Name))).Data;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's look like you are asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

The solution to get new name of class / property:

Create your class with **DisplayNameAttribute** as follow:

```
[DisplayName("something")]
public class Car
{
    [DisplayName("something_else")]
    public string color { get; set; }

    public int VINCode { get; set; }
}
```

To get your class attribute name:

```
var attributes = typeof(Car) // type declaration
        
        .CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault() // first item of collection that contains this member's custom attributes like [DisplayName("something")]
        
        ?.ConstructorArguments.FirstOrDefault() // first item of structure collecion
        
        .Value; // value as string - "something"
```

Similarly to the property name, you only need to get its type first

```
var attribute = typeof(Car).GetProperty(nameof(Car.color)) // ...
```

instead of

```
var attribute = typeof(Car) // ...
```

Comment: It's also possible to use `typeof(...).GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()` to get attribute of given type. Useful when several attributes are defined